# factorize a php object separate the methods for a joomla component

Tags: php, joomla

I am currently creating a component for joomla, so I use PHP in POO with the MVC model of joomla! For my component I end up with a huge code of more than 3800 lines, I would like to factorize / separate this code so that it is more readable later.

To do this I would therefore like to separate the methods in a separate file in order to recall them in the code.

I tested several solution but which does not work, I mi a method in a file methode.php, I then used include ('methode.php'); but I have the impression that it does not work in an object.

I also tested the require and require_ once. as well as a joomla! : jimport ('method.php');

I think there is a relatively accessible solution to this problem, however I can not find a solution with my research.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla loads classes, the method declarations need to be in the class that Joomla imports. I am not sure how the autoloader interferes with requires and imports. I would go about using inheritage. Build a base class that inherits from the appropriate joomla class and inherit a few times with incresing functionality. Not the intuitive way, but that's how I see Joomla do it.

Comment: I found the solution to my problem, I had to load the class with the Jloader :: register proposed by joomla, it is actually very useful for placing classes in the framwork directly. subject closed.